Quarkus Panache loads only one of two foreign key referenced entities
I'm working on implementing a quarkus backend for an already populated sports scoring database. I have three tables, disciplines, sport_categories, and competition_formats. Disciplines have foreign keys to the two other tables.
I have Entity classes, extending PanacheBaseEntity. Here is how the DisciplineEntity class looks:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "disciplines")
public class DisciplineEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sport_category_id", nullable = false)
    private SportCategoryEntity sportCategory;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "competition_format_id", nullable = false)
    private CompetitionFormatEntity competitionFormat;
    ...

When I call DisciplineEntity.findById(disciplineId), I get a weird result. The sportCategory comes back as a fully populated object. While the competitionFormat only has it's id. I see absolutely no difference in how the two foreign key references are written in DisciplineEntity class, and I don't understand why they behave differently.
I have double checked that all String variables are correct. And if i call CompetitionFormatEntity.listAll(), they return fully populated. This should mean that I don't have any typos in the code, related to column names in the competition_formats table.
What in the world can cause this kind of weird behavior?
